# Insert video background in jsp this : Here the code is not playing video . 'm using netbeans and its jsp

Tags: html, html5-video

```
<div class="background-wrap">
  <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted"> 
    <source src="C:\Users\PraveenkumarNaik\Downloads\Logan.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Video not supported
  </video>          
</div>
```

Insert video background in HTML this: the above code is not playing video.

Comment: Does C:\Users\PraveenkumarNaik\Downloads\Logan.mp4 exist?

Comment: yes.... it's working if save it in html format... but not in jsp

Comment: You got console errors?

Comment: No errors.. i just get a blank web page ... if possible just run similar code in jsp and let me know if it works fine... I hope u don't mind